# Assigning user dropdown selection to variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capture a value from a drop down menu and print that value to the console using jquery. However I'm getting a strange response in the console I've not seen before and don't know what to make of. My code is below

```
function watchForm(){
  let howManyDogs=$('#dogNumber option:selected').val(); 
  $('form').submit(event=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(howManyDogs));
  });
}
```

when running the above function, I get the following message in the console :
**{ length: 0,
prevObject: { 0: HTMLDocument { location: [Getter/Setter] }, length: 1 } }**

however if I run

```
console.log($('#dogNumber option:selected').val());
```

It prints the number selected, which is what I want. I want to make sure I have my variable set correctly so I can reference it elsewhere. Can someone help point out my issue? Thanks so much!

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a jQuery object to an already jQuery object, so simply remove `$()` around `howManyDogs`,

Also if you are going to save the selected option in a variable, you need to listen to `change` event for select, if you don't wanna do that, you can check the value from option by inserting the value directly in the submit listener

```js
function watchForm() {
  $('form').on('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $('#dogNumber option:selected').val());
  });
}

watchForm()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <select id="dogNumber">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```